# assign from lookupedit selected item

Tags: c#, devexpress

Is there any method like this:

```
 product.supplier = combobox.SelectedItem as suppier
```

in devexpress `LookUpEdit`?

Comment: I would recommend looking at this: http://bit.ly/XVNcMp

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use approach demonstrated in the following KB-article:
[How to obtain the selected row from the LookUp editor](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A495.aspx)

PS. The official [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) is much better than Google or Stackoverflow when you are searching anything related to DevExpress controls.